# How to insert an answer into python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a game using python and I attempted to insert a question but I do not know how to put in the answer.

For example,

print ("What is the most popular search engine?")

## I am unsure what to put after this. In addition, I don't know how to make python move on to the next question.

Comment: Check out [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get it so that Python asks the user "What is the most popular search engine?" and then stores the answer in a variable then you should use the `input()` method.

```
popularSearchEngine = input("What is the most popular search engine? ")
```

What this does it it prints "What is the most popular search engine?" and then waits for the user to enter something. Whatever the user enters is then stored in the variable `popularSearchEngine`.

Now, if you wanted to check to see if the user entered 'google', you could just use a basic if statement. I would recommend using `strip()` and `lower()` so that what the user enters does not have to be case-sensitive.

```
popularSearchEngine = input("What is the most popular search engine? ")

if popularSearchEngine.strip().lower() == 'google':
    # Run this code if user enters 'GOOGLE' or 'GooGLE' or '  gOoGlE'
```

Comment: Good job on your first answer. Very detailed and neat! Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Th3Gam3rz if previous to this one. I didn't understood correctly the question before. I edited the answer in order to be correct.

If you want to make a question and read the input of the other person you can do:

```
answer=input("What is the most popular search engine?\n")
```

And the answer will be storedd in answer

Comment: Sorry I do understand what it is saying but can you please add on to my code. Like would I have to put input = Google

Comment: @Kevitsu If I'm not wrong the prblem you are facing is that you want to print a question but if you write 'print("What is the most popular search engine?")' python rayses an error because it doesn't now how to read the ? because it is not a valid symbol. There are a couple of solutions for avoiding that error. One of them is telling python that you want to print exactly what you write, that it should not woory about what is inside the string. For doing that you have to write an r before opening the string as in my solution print(r"What is the most popular search engine?") note the r after the(

Comment: @Hadrián I don't think this is right. You do not need the r. His real question is how do you ask the user for a response.

Comment: @DeliriousSyntax Aaah, ok, I thought he had the problem with that. And you are right, it is not necessary, I will update the answer now. Thanks!:)

Comment: @Hadrián tell me when you fix your answer, so I can +1

Comment: @DeliriousSyntax It is  already changed, but there is now a more complete answer to the question.